# How to display custom texts upon kendo chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to display custom dynamic texts upon my kendo chart. Those texts value come from chart datasource only

Please see below image 
[image]

Comment: if your annotations are associated with points on the chart, you could use the series notes feature (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.notes). Otherwise you could use the render event to draw your own ssvg text on the chart...

Comment: Do you have an example for render event to draw your own ssvg text on the chart?

Comment: And one more thing you can see on image my texts are not connected with columns

Comment: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/BWGMZa